# Sum with multiple conditions returned by index

Tags: excel, indexing

I have to calculate the sum of 3 set of data based on different conditions as below:

1. Product specific target for Sale position
2. Sale team formation: to determine if a specific Sale target is counted for the team leader (1= Y, 0=N). if value is 0, then target of this sale is not counted for sale team leader even he/she is in the team.
3. Number of Sale in the team

These conditions are in separate tables.

Team leader target of each product = Number of Sale * Product specific target * team formation

Each condition i used Index/match to return the results. I have tried to use Sumproduct to return Team leader target but it only compute for 1 Sale position, not for every Sale position this Team leader manage.

For example:

Table 1: Sale target of each position- given by index from another spreadsheet based on role
Role       |Deposit |Lending
Senior RM  |10,000  |400,000
RM         |0       |300,000
Junior RM  |20,000  |200,000
PFC        |30,000  |30,000

Table 2 - Target counts for Team leader - given by index formula based type of team leader after team leader choose their type.
Choose type ==> (drop down list here)
Role            |Senior RM  |RM   |Junior RM |PFC
PB Team Leader  |1          |1    |1         |0
PFC Team Leader |0          |0    |1         |1
Auto Specialist |0          |0    |0         |1

Table 3
Team leader A's team members: self-input by team leader
Team Member  |FTE
Senior RM    |2
RM           |2
Junior RM    |1
PFC          |3

Team MemberFTESenior RM2RM2Junior RM1PFC3

My outcome table for Team leader is as below:

```
Table 4
```

Team leader target
            |  Total Target 
    Deposit |   Total
    Loans   |   Total

I would like to have a single formula to calculate the total base on Team Leader type, their team formation and product target specific to sale.

Comment: you do not need Team leader a team formation  or point 2 from your question if you have a table that tells you how many people are on the team and in which positions, unless its possible to have 2 junior sales people as part of team A but in terms of team formation Junior sales is 0.

Comment: To me it is simply not obvious how to pull the data... your *"Team leader a team formation:"*-table does not match your example... right now nothing Ican see in your question makes any sense... You have lists you need to pull the data from... how do they look like?

Comment: sorry, very new to ask question here, how can i attached sample file? or draw table here?

Comment: Your example data is pretty good, the problem is drawing the relation on how they are developed.  [This web site is not a bad tool for copying tables from excel and pasting them into your question as text](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).  It does not deal with empty cells correctly so if you have empty cells, you might want to temporarily put a * in them and then go back and replace the * with a space when you past it into your question.

Comment: i tried to edit tables but it seems lacking something, please kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Start by building out your Team information table.  Make adjacent columns Team B then Team C and so one.  See screen shot:

*Table A*

[image: Team Table]

Have your Target of sales table just as you displayed:

*Table B*

[image]

And then build out your report table as follows

*Table C*

[image] [image]

now to achieve this take note of the naming in the header rows (B6:D6) and the selected team in B12.

I used data validation to create a drop down least to choose the team you were looking for.

In order to perform the calculation and making it dependent on the choosen team name and of the name of the item to the left ie. Deposts or Loans, I used the following equation in B13 and copied it to 14:

```
=SUM(MMULT(INDEX($B$3:$D$4,MATCH($A13,$A$3:$A$4,0),0),INDEX($B$8:$D$10,,MATCH($B$12,$B$6:$D$6,0))))
```

It identifies the row or column in the Team Composition table and Target Sales table.  it then performs a matrix multiply.  this is important as we need to transpose the row to multiply it with the column.  after the matrix multiplication we sum the resulting matrix to wind up with your total.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In my spreadsheet, the number of Sale in each team is for user input. Hence, team leader will choose their name and input the number of sale in each position, would the formula still work? for the team formation part, it is my error check so that even Team leader input wrong sale position, the target is still correct

Comment: I have numbered your tables in your question and now waiting for the edits to be peer reviewed.  I numbered your tables Table 1, Table 2, Table 3 and Table 4 in the other that information is supplied.  So as not to confuse your tables with the tables in my answer, I have labelled my tables Table A, B and C.

Comment: The concept of the formula should still work.  your may need to modify it to suit you needs.  "the number of Sale in each team"  What table is this?  You say choose their name, but none of your tables show person name choice so a little confused as to what name choice is.

Comment: My table A is a combination of your Table 1 and Table 3, while your table three will eliminate # of people assigned in a wrong position, it will not move them to the correct position.  You can flag a problem by doing the calculation with just your Table 1 or my Table A and then doing it again with your Table 3 added in and comparing the difference.  if there is a difference, you have something in the wrong category, no difference then everything MIGHT be right.  I say might because it will not tell you if the put someone in the wrong position, but that position is still part of the team.